# How do I make it so that my turtle cannot cross the lines inside of my box?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a labyrinth where the turtle has to only go one way to make it to the other side, but it can't cross any lines so the user can't cheat.

I have tried making lines that would stop the turtle and it worked but I can't make it so that the turtle just doesn't pass the lines and lets me keep moving to complete the maze. I kind of want it to work like I have the outside barrier working to where you can't leave the maze. I don't want it to be lines the turtle draws and can't cross I want it to be only the lines I have in place already.

The code I have now is:

```py
import turtle

# Set up the screen
screen = turtle.Screen()
x_min, y_min = -250, -250
x_max, y_max = 250, 250
screen.setup(600, 600)
screen.bgcolor("white")
screen.title("Labyrinth Game")
screen.bgcolor("darkgoldenrod")
# Draw the maze
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.pensize(5)
pen.color("black")
pen.penup()
pen.goto(-250, 250)
pen.pendown()
pen.forward(500)
pen.right(90)
pen.forward(500)
pen.penup()
pen.right(90)
pen.forward(50)
pen.pendown()
pen.forward(450)
pen.right(90)
pen.forward(500)
pen.right(90)
pen.forward(200)
pen.right(90)
pen.forward(300)
pen.right(90)
pen.forward(50)
pen.penup()
pen.forward(50)
pen.pendown()
pen.forward(100)
pen.penup()
pen.backward(200)
pen.pendown()
pen.left(180)
pen.forward(50)
pen.penup()
pen.forward(50)
pen.pendown()
pen.forward(50)
pen.right(90)
pen.forward(200)
pen.backward(200)
pen.right(180)
pen.forward(200)
pen.backward(50)
pen.left(45)
pen.forward(100)
pen.backward(100)
pen.right(45)
pen.backward(100)
pen.right(135)
pen.forward(100)
pen.penup()
pen.left(45)
pen.forward(78)
pen.right(90)
pen.backward(20)
pen.right(45)
pen.pendown()
pen.forward(100)
pen.penup()
pen.goto(-50,60)
pen.pendown()
pen.left(90)
pen.forward(100)
pen.backward(100)
pen.right(45)
pen.forward(112)
pen.left(45)
pen.forward(140)
pen.right(45)
pen.penup()
pen.forward(99)
pen.pendown()
pen.right(90)
pen.forward(50)
pen.right(45)
pen.forward(140)
pen.right(45)
pen.penup()
pen.forward(100)
pen.pendown()
pen.left(135)
pen.forward(150)
pen.left(90)
pen.forward(75)
pen.left(45)
pen.penup()
pen.forward(403)
pen.pendown()
pen.left(90)
pen.forward(200)
pen.left(45)
pen.forward(100)
pen.left(45)
pen.penup()
pen.forward(75)
pen.pendown()
pen.right(135)
pen.forward(150)
pen.left(45)
pen.penup()
pen.forward(80)
pen.pendown()
pen.left(135)
pen.forward(100)


# Create the player
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.shape("circle")
player.color("grey")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.goto(230,-250) 


# Set up the keyboard controls
def in_bounds(t):
  x, y = player.position()
  return x_min < x < x_max and y_min < y < y_max

def go_up():
  player.setheading(90)
  player.forward(10)
  if not in_bounds(player):
    player.backward(10)

def go_down():
  player.setheading(270)
  player.forward(10)
  if not in_bounds(player):
    player.backward(10)

def go_left():
  player.setheading(180)
  player.forward(10)
  if not in_bounds(player):
    player.backward(10)

def go_right():
  player.setheading(0)
  player.forward(10)
  if not in_bounds(player):
    player.backward(10)

screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(go_up, "Up")
screen.onkeypress(go_down, "Down")
screen.onkeypress(go_left, "Left")
screen.onkeypress(go_right, "Right")

turtle.done()
```

Comment: You need to save the wall pieces in a data structure, then at each move check for a collision against each one. I suggest using absolute positioning and `pen.goto()` to draw them

Answer (score 1):

For one, we need to remember where the walls are. To do that, we can store the walls in a simple format that stores the start and end point of each line, and then set up a function to draw all those lines:

```
# Draw the maze
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.pensize(5)
pen.color("black")
pen.penup()

# Define walls
walls = [
    ((-150, 150), (150, 150)),
    ((-150, 150), (-150, -150)),
    #...more walls defined here
]


def draw_wall(wall):
    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(*wall[0])
    pen.pendown()
    pen.goto(*wall[1])
    pen.penup()


for wall in walls:
    draw_wall(wall)
```

Now, let's put movement in a function that handles collision and bounds, so that we simply request to move to a spot, and the function decides where we ended up:

```
def move_towards(x, y, move_distance, walls):
    if in_bounds(x, y, move_distance) and not collides_with_wall(x, y, walls):
        player.goto(x, y)
```

To determine if we're in bounds:

```
def in_bounds(x, y, move_distance):
    return x_min + move_distance < x < x_max - move_distance and y_min + move_distance < y < y_max - move_distance
```

And here's the most complicated code; it checks if you're colliding with a wall:

```
def collides_with_wall(x, y, walls):
    tolerance = 2  # To account for floating-point inaccuracies
    for wall in walls:
        (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = wall
        if abs(x1 - x2) <= tolerance:  # vertical wall
            if min(y1, y2) <= y <= max(y1, y2) and abs(x - x1) <= move_distance:
                return True
        elif abs(y1 - y2) <= tolerance:  # horizontal wall
            if min(x1, x2) <= x <= max(x1, x2) and abs(y - y1) <= move_distance:
                return True
    return False
```

Your movement functions then just have to look like:

```
def go_down():
    x, y = player.position()
    move_towards(x, y - move_distance, move_distance, walls)


def go_left():
    x, y = player.position()
    move_towards(x - move_distance, y, move_distance, walls)
```

And etc. Putting it all together we get:

```
import turtle


def in_bounds(x, y, move_distance):
    return x_min + move_distance < x < x_max - move_distance and y_min + move_distance < y < y_max - move_distance


def collides_with_wall(x, y, walls):
    tolerance = 2  # To account for floating-point inaccuracies
    for wall in walls:
        (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = wall
        if abs(x1 - x2) <= tolerance:  # vertical wall
            if min(y1, y2) <= y <= max(y1, y2) and abs(x - x1) <= move_distance:
                return True
        elif abs(y1 - y2) <= tolerance:  # horizontal wall
            if min(x1, x2) <= x <= max(x1, x2) and abs(y - y1) <= move_distance:
                return True
    return False


def move_towards(x, y, move_distance, walls):
    if in_bounds(x, y, move_distance) and not collides_with_wall(x, y, walls):
        player.goto(x, y)


def go_up():
    x, y = player.position()
    move_towards(x, y + move_distance, move_distance, walls)


def go_down():
    x, y = player.position()
    move_towards(x, y - move_distance, move_distance, walls)


def go_left():
    x, y = player.position()
    move_towards(x - move_distance, y, move_distance, walls)


def go_right():
    x, y = player.position()
    move_towards(x + move_distance, y, move_distance, walls)


# Set up the screen
screen = turtle.Screen()
x_min, y_min = -250, -250
x_max, y_max = 250, 250
move_distance = 10
screen.setup(600, 600)
screen.bgcolor("white")
screen.title("Labyrinth Game")
screen.bgcolor("darkgoldenrod")

# Draw the maze
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.pensize(5)
pen.color("black")
pen.penup()

# Define walls
walls = [
    ((-150, 150), (150, 150)),
    ((-150, 150), (-150, -150)),
    #...more walls defined here
]


def draw_wall(wall):
    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(*wall[0])
    pen.pendown()
    pen.goto(*wall[1])
    pen.penup()


for wall in walls:
    draw_wall(wall)

# Create the player
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.shape("circle")
player.color("grey")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.goto(0, 0)

# Set up the keyboard controls
screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(go_up, "Up")
screen.onkeypress(go_down, "Down")
screen.onkeypress(go_left, "Left")
screen.onkeypress(go_right, "Right")

while True:
    screen.update()
```

Should be good enough to get you started. You'll have to play around with movement distance, tolerances, etc in order to get it feeling right, but the basic logic is all there.